# Create Items through splitting a string by comma(,) and add them to the collection

Tags: vba

I have a collection called as `SheetNameCollection` and I have a string called as SheetNames.

Here goes my code,

```
Dim SheetNames As String
Dim SheetNameCollection As Collection
Set SheetNameCollection = New Collection
SheetNames = "wk1,wk2,wk3,wk4"
'This is dynamic and will usually be more than 100 sheets.
```

I am looking for a way to add these SheetNames one by one into my collection SheetNameCollection.

Kindly suggest an approach. Thanks.

Comment: Use `Split()` function and then iterate through the return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Scott Craner pointed out.

Split the names into an array and then iterate over each name in the array adding it to the collection.

```
Dim item As Variant
For Each item In Split(SheetNames, ",")
    SheetNameCollection.Add item
Next
```